# Kubuntu 21.04 night color not working

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 21.04, redshift, kwin

My system doesn't starts with night color (I have set it to be always on).

Occasionally while I am using my system it starts the night color filter for 2-3 seconds and then it turns off. However the night light indicator on my panel stays on.

If I explicitly restart night color, it shows the same behavior, i.e. turns on the night color and then auto shuts down. The same behavior is seen when I run `redshift -O 3000` i.e. the filter starts for a few second and shuts down, while displaying the following message on terminal.

```
Could not connect to wayland display, exiting.
Failed to start adjustment method wayland.
Trying next method...
Using method `randr'.
```

Logs related containing redshift as keyword in `journalctl`

I get the following log repeated number of times in journalctl. (consecutively multiple times).

```
audit[648]: USER_AVC pid=648 uid=103 auid=4294967295 
ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined 
msg='apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="dbus_method_call"  
bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/DBus" 
interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="GetNameOwner" mask="send" 
name="org.freedesktop.DBus" pid=30830 
label="/usr/bin/redshift" peer_label="unconfined"                              
exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

these logs repeateadly occur in my /var/log/syslog

```
19:42:33 dbus-daemon[648]: [system] Activating service name='org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper'
requested by ':1.55' (uid=1000 pid=3546 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec
/org_kde_powerdev" label="unconfined") (using servicehelper)

19:42:33 dbus-daemon[648]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper'

19:44:22 kernel: [ 8808.087955] audit: type=1107 audit(1627481662.927:99): pid=648
uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined 
msg='apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" 
path="/org/freedesktop/GeoClue2/Client/1/Location/0" 
interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="PropertiesChanged" name=":1.43" 
mask="receive" pid=2636 label="/usr/bin/redshift" 
peer_pid=2656 peer_label="unconfined"

19:44:22 kernel: [ 8808.087955]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
```

This issue was not from the very start, it has recently creeped in. Recently I have only installed updates from KDE-discover, changed my display resolution from 1920x1080 to 1600x900 and tried to fix my Nvidia driver issues by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt purge *nvidia*
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

System info:

```
OS: Kubuntu 21.04 x86_64 
Kernel: 5.11.0-25-generic   
Shell: bash 5.1.4 
Resolution: 1600x900 
DE: Plasma 5.21.4 
WM: KWin 
WM Theme: Breeze 
Theme: Breeze Dark [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: breeze-dark [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 
CPU: Intel i5-8265U (8) @ 3.900GHz 
GPU: Intel WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620] 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX250 
Memory: 2090MiB / 7798MiB
```

I have checked other forums and github of kde and redshift. I don't understand how to fix this, nor I know that the logs that I mentioned are useful. Please let me know if I need to attach some other logs.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed for me. This is what I did.

- I had previously installed `redshift` and `redshift-gtk` in attempts to fix this issue but they didn't worked out and they seemed to have worsen the issue, so I **removed** them

```
sudo apt remove redshift redshift-gtk
sudo apt autoremove
```

- When I looked back into my night color preferences, I noticed somehow the the Activation Time was reset to be "Sunset to Sunrise at current location" which depends upon location data to work right. I changed it to be "Always on", however I think other options like "Sunset to Sunrise at manual location" and "Custom Time" should also work.
- I restarted the system.

The logs I reported in the question, didn't came up after this reboot. And night color since then seems to be working fine.